# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Tags: c#, localdb

Below code gives me output in datagridview it was previously working fine ande now it is giving me System.Stackoverflow error

[image]

---

```
static class SqlFunctions
{
    static private SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bazardb.sdf");

    static public void refresh(DataGridView datagrid)
    {
        try
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCeDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from item", con);
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            dataadapter.Fill(datatable);
            datagrid.DataSource = datatable;

        }
        catch (SqlCeException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: datagrid.BeginUpdate(); datagrid.DataSource = datat; datagrid.EndUpdate(); ??

Comment: debug the code. At what line does the exception throw? Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: it shows error to dataadapter line

Comment: I'm guessing there is a loop here somewhere? and your refreshing it constantly?

Comment: nope only on form load i fill gridview or on update i refresh it

Comment: this is a Java question but the same applies here [What is a StackOverflowError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror)

Comment: FYI this code is a memory leak waiting to happen, dispose of your objects.

Comment: @smart_coder How many results are you expecting to be returned by this query? Try and limit the results to see if it resolves to which will help troubleshoot.

Comment: @Liam it was previously showing error that connection is open,so i handled it by checking if connectionstate.isopen  after that it is giving me this error ,i ll try to search if their is any recursive call

Comment: If you posted the stack trace as @CathalMF has suggested it'd make it much easier to identify the issue

Comment: @CathalMF i want results more than 1K may be coz i am showing item list, rightnow am testing with only 10-15 rows

Comment: @smart_coder You need to post the stack trace. Select the "View Detail" on the exception in visual studio and copy the stack trace value and post it to the question.

Comment: {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}   -this details are shown when i clicked View Detail